# Selecting certain tuple based on elements in a tuple filled list

Tags: python, search, nlp

I am doing some NLP with NLTK and I have a Counter() sequences, for example

```
x = [(('DT', 'NN'), 59), (('NN', '.'), 50)]
```

After searching I should end up with a list of all the tuples with the above requirement.

```
y = [(('DT', 'NN'), 59)]
```

My question is, how can I efficiently select all the elements that have 'DT' as the first element of the inner tuple without O(n) time, in the most pythony way?

Comment: Not possible with the current data structure, unless you remap that list to a mapping such that the first element of the 2-tuple key be the key, and form a new 2-tuple with the second element of the 2-tuple key and the count and append that to a list. This would be a single O(n) operation but the resulting lookup from that new structure will have the standard time complexity from looking up data from a `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As metatoaster has elaborated in his comment, you would prob. have to restructure your data to perform the operation in the exact way you want (without O(n)).

That being said, in the current state and with reference to your example, you could do:

```
y = [t for t in x if t[0][0] == 'DT']
```